# Composing arbitrary functions in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am following category theory for programmers and trying to implement a compose function in Python. What I have currently is

```py
def compose(f, g):
    def result(*args):
        return f(g(*args))
    return result


def square(x):
    return x * x


def add(x, y):
    return x + y


def f(x, y):
    return min(x, y)


def g(x, y):
    return x + y, x * y


result = compose(square, add)(1, 2)
print(result)

result = compose(f, g)(1, 2)
print(result)
```

But this will not work because I don't know whether `g(*args)` in `compose` will return an object which is an iterator or just a single return value. Is there a way to write `compose` in Python without using `isinstance`??

Answer (score 0):

One option is to always return a list; then you can unpack g without checking:

```py
def compose(f, g):
    def result(*args):
        return f(*g(*args)) # we can unpack g here if we know every function returns a list
    return result

def square(x):
    return [x * x]

def add(x, y):
    return [x + y]

def f(x, y):
    return [min(x, y)]

def g(x, y):
    return x + y, x * y

result = compose(square, add)(1, 2)
print(result)

result = compose(f, g)(1, 2)
print(result)
```